# How to show a vertical text when an hover effect is active

Tags: html, css, text, hover

I'm working on an amateur website and I create 2 `<div>` (2 rectangles) overlapped each other and when hover is active I also want to show a vertical text on the lower `<div>` but I tried different methods but can't figure out how to make that happen.

```css
#rectangle2 {
  background-color: #fd9e0e;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.73s;
}

#rectangle {
  width: 650px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #147906;
}

#rectangle text {
  display: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
}

#rectangle2:hover {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

#rectangle2:hover text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
  <text>SUMMER</text>
  <div id="rectangle2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you mean "show a text using HTML and CSS only"? Because you could use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```
#rectangle2:hover text { display: block;}
```

should be

```
#rectangle2:hover ~ text { display: block;}
```

its the `~`

Answer (score 0):

You select the item that is below the one you need to select.

In this case you have to select the wrapper element that is `#rectangle` and then set what should happen to those who are in it `#rectangle2` and `text`

```css
#rectangle2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: #fd9e0e;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.73s;
}

#rectangle {
    width: 650px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #147906;
    position: relative;
}

#rectangle text {
    /* display: none; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#rectangle:hover #rectangle2 {
    margin-left: 70px;
}

#rectangle:hover text {
    /* display: block; */
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
    <text>SUMMER</text>
    <div id="rectangle2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the hovering which show's the text from rectangle2 to rectangle.

```
#rectangle:hover text {
  display: block;
}
```

And also change the `writing-mode` to `vertical-lr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation keyframes for this. Also I added a position of absolute to the hover element element as well. I also used opacity instead of display. Using a keyframe animation gives it a smooth effect easing in the text on the hover.

```css
#rectangle2 {
  background-color: #fd9e0e;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.73s;
}

#rectangle {
  width: 650px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #147906;
}

#rectangle text {
  opacity: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  position: absolute;
}

#rectangle:hover #rectangle2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

#rectangle:hover text {
  -webkit-animation: show .73s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: show .73s ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: show .73s ease-in-out;
  animation: show .73s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
  <text>SUMMER</text>
  <div id="rectangle2"></div>
</div>
```